# Algorithm for optimizing Ax = b with unknown A and known x values

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse-problem

I would like to solve for the optimum $A$ values for a series of matrix equations $Ax_{1} = b_{1}, Ax_{2} = b_{2} ... Ax_{n} = b_{n}$ where only the $x$ values are known and when I start with an intelligent guess for $A$. I am using QR decomposition to solve the individual matrix equations for $b$, but wondering how to go about optimizing $A$ values as I don't have a real $b$ value to use in defining some error metric to use for convergence.

The nature of the problem is that $x$ is a set of sensor values and $A$ represents a set of constant coefficients defining to what degree the value at an adjacent sensor affects the measured values of $x$. The $b$ values should be the actual values without superposition from other sensors.

Any suggestions on tackling this would be appreciated.

Comment: Since you're using QR, are you doing least-squares fitting?

Comment: How would you quantify whether $A$ has an optimum value or not? Do you have any idea what $b_n$ should look like?

Comment: Why do you need QR to solve for $b_n$, can't you just multiply?

Comment: I am doing least squares as the values aren't going be exact and I am trying to derive the "best" A coefficients for a whole set of data points. I need the best fit since these are sensor readings and not the real, independent values that I would like to extract, but don't know if A has an optimum value or more than one. Bill, you are probably might be right that straight multiplication would work for this portion. My biggest problems is really getting that "best" A matrix such that I can tease out the actual values from my readings.

Comment: @Jason, if you want to formulate your problem as $Q_i R_i x_i=b_i$ so that the your $A_i$ is directly constructed from its SVD, that might be one approach instead of trying to optimize entries individually. It certainly provides some structure to your approach, but I don't think you need to be factoring your $A_i$ using QR since multiplication is massively cheaper.

Comment: I think that ICA mentioned below is what I need. Thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: The title and the question say two different things. It would be useful if you edited and specified clearly what is given and what is an unknown. Also, what are the matrix sizes? Are they related to $n$? And please avoid the term "series", in mathematics it means something else and it can be confusing.

Comment: I have updated the title to make it clearer and more related to the details of the question. The matrix sizes vary and did not seem relevant to the question so were not mentioned. What would be a better term than series?

Comment: The matrix size is definitely relevant.  If $n$ is less than the size of $A$, then this is an underdetermined system and you can find an infinite number of $A$ matrices that yield an error of zero on your set of measurements (assuming your data does not contradict itself).  If $n$ is exactly the size of $A$ (i.e., $A$ is $n \times n$), then you get exactly one $A$ which is a perfect fit.  If $n$ is larger than the size of $A$, then you have an overdetermined system and some sort of least squares fitting will have to be done.  Also, instead of series, you could say "system of matrix equations."

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So how would I describe the n value in this situation where n matches the size of the A matrix? What is the equation called if not over or under determined?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem sounds like Independent Component Analysis. Where $x_i$ are the measurements in which the source signals have got mixed and $b_i$ are the values emitted by the sources. The $A$ in your equations is called the unmixing matrix. There is an iterative procedure to estimate $A$ and hence, the $b_i$s, based on the maximum likelihood principle. Refer to these notes:

[Andrew Ng's notes on ICA](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes11.pdf)

[Edit] FastICA looks like a popular implementation:

http://research.ics.aalto.fi/ica/fastica/

http://itpp.sourceforge.net/4.3.0/fastica_8cpp.html

http://tumic.wz.cz/fel/online/libICA/

[Edit] The OP (Jason) also found these for future reference:

https://github.com/cgearhart/students-filters/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/fastica/

http://shulgadim.blogspot.ca/2014/02/independent-component-analysis-ica.html

Comment: This does look like the sort of thing I need. I am going to try it out and get back. If you know of some implementations, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for these. I also found and have added some. I have a few to try out. Many thanks.

Comment: Answer accepted. (It was the first one I accepted so wasn't sure what I was looking for at first)

Answer (score 1):

Reformulate your set of equations such that the coefficients are the unknowns and perform least square fitting on A.

This can be done by the following trick:

Be $x$ a column vector $(n\times 1)$, $A$ the unknown matrix $(n\times n)$,
you know that $Ax =b \Rightarrow  \sum_j a_{ij} x_j = b_i$ but this can also be seen as $\hat X\, \textrm{Vec}(A)= b$ where $\textrm{Vec}(A)$ is the [vectorization operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) and $\hat X$ must be n-times repeated and shifted by n $x^T$ or $0^T$ otherwise, leading to $\Rightarrow \hat X=x^T\otimes I_n $, where $I_n$ is the identity matrix of dimension n.

For the full system you can rewrite it as following,
set $X=(x_1,...,x_n)$ and $B=(b_1,...,b_n)$ of your original equations $A X = B$, your least square problem for $A$ reads $(X^T\otimes I_n)\textrm{Vec}(A)=\textrm{Vec}(B)$.

So it all boils down if you have enough matrix equations whether this will be an over or undertemined system and can be directly solved by standard numerical techniques.